# PowerShell creating a log

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm writing a script which replaces a lot of lines in some specific properties/files. Now I'm almost done but I need to do a log for testing etc. But I have no Idea how. I searched for a lot of options like functions and stuff like this but I don't get it. So I need your help.

Thanks and sorry for being an amateur!

```
#Config.ps1 laden
. \\imbo\imbo$\03_Applikationen\03_27_customizing_sapbo_script\Umsetzung\config.ps1



#-----------------------------Input-------------------------------------------------------

#Abfrage für die Umgebung
$env = Read-Host -Prompt "@PROD, @INT, @DEV, @ADM, @PRD_EXT, @INT_EXT "



#-----------------------------Copy-Jobs---------------------------------------------------
#Property-Files kopieren
Copy-Item -Path $propertyfiles -Destination $1war1, $1war2

#Bilder kopieren
Copy-Item -Path $sap_logo -Destination
Copy-Item -Path $post_logo -Destination
Copy-Item -Path $images_src -Destination $images_dst

#Custom kopieren
Copy-Item -Path $custom_src -Destination $custom_dst1, $custom_dst2


#-----------------------------WAR-Files---------------------------------------------------

#WAR-Files

ForEach($Datei in Get-ChildItem $1war1, $1war2, $2war1, $2war2, $3war1, $3war2, $4war1, $4war2, $5war1, $5war2, $6war1, $6war2, $7war1, $7war2, $8war1, $8war2, $9war1, $9war2, $cluster1, $cluster2) {

    # Get-Content liest eine Texdatei oder mehrere Zeile für Zeile ein
    # in der Variablen $Zeilen steht deshalb eine Liste von Zeilen (Array)
    $Zeilen =  Get-Content -Path $Datei.Fullname
    # Die Datei befindet sich nun Komplett im Speicher (in der Variablen $Zeilen)
    # deshalb können wir die Datei überschreiben

    # Zeilen Zähler, wird nur gebraucht um die erste Zeile zu erkennen
    $ZeilenZähler = 1

    # jede Zeile abarbeiten
    foreach($Zeile in $Zeilen)
    {
        # Hier findet meine Dateiveränderung statt.
        # Beispiel: Alle Buchstaben 'a' durch den Buchstaben 'o' ersetzen
        #.+ ist dazu da um dem Programm zu sagen dass hier eigentlich noch mehr kommt aber dies nicht bekannt ist
        #\d+ steht für Ziffern aber man weiss auch hier nicht welche
        if($env -eq '@PROD' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princp"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princps.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$env"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
        }
        elseif($env -eq '@INT' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princi"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princis.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$env"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
        }
        elseif($env -eq '@DEV' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princd"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princds.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$env"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
        }
        elseif($env -eq '@ADM' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princa"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princas.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$env"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
        }
        elseif($env -eq '@PRD_EXT' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princpe"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princpes.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$princpesrv"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
            #cms.visible BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.visible=.+","cms.visible=false"
            #authentification.visible BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "authentication.visible=.+","authentication.visible=false"
            #authentification.default BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "authentification.default=.+","authentification.default=secEnterprise"
            #PostLogout_html kopieren
            Copy-Item -Path $logout_src -Destination $logout_dst
        }
        elseif($env -eq '@INT_EXT' ) {
            #global.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "max.tree.children.threshold=\d+","max.tree.children.threshold=300"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.princ=.+/.+","idm.princ=$princie"
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "idm.keytab=D:/sso/.+.keytab","idm.keytab=D:/sso/$princies.keytab"
            #BIlaunchpad.propertiers, CmcApp.properties, OpenDocument.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.default=.+","cms.default=$princiesrv"
            #Session-Timeouts
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "session-timeout>\d+</session-timeout>","session-timeout>120</session-timeout>"
            #Kerberos-Filter aktivieren
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "<!--123",""
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "321-->",""
            #cms.visible BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "cms.visible=.+","cms.visible=false"
            #authentification.visible BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "authentication.visible=.+","authentication.visible=false"
            #authentification.default BIlaunchpad.properties und CmcApp.properties
            $Zeile = $Zeile -replace "authentification.default=.+","authentification.default=secEnterprise"
            #PostLogout_html kopieren
            Copy-Item -Path $logout_src -Destination $logout_dst
        }


        # Nur bei der ersten Zeile wird die Alte Datei ("leer") neu angelegt (überschrieben)!
        If($ZeilenZähler -eq 1 ) {
           Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force
        }
        Else {
            # jede weitere Zeile an die neue erstellte Datei anhängen (Parameter Append)
            Out-File -FilePath $Datei.Fullname -InputObject $Zeile -Force -Append
        }

        # Zeilenzähler hochsetzen
        $ZeilenZähler++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a log function like this

```
function Write-Host 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [Alias("LogContent")] 
        [string]$Message, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [Alias('LogPath')] 
        [string]$Path='c:\LogFile.log',       #creating Log file with current date
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [ValidateSet("Error","Warn","Info")] 
        [string]$Level="Info", 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [switch]$NoClobber 
    ) 

    Begin 
    { 
        # Set VerbosePreference to Continue so that verbose messages are displayed. 
        $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' 
    } 
    Process 
    {
        # If the file already exists and NoClobber was specified, do not write to the log. 
        if ((Test-Path $Path) -AND $NoClobber) { 
            Write-Error "Log file $Path already exists, and you specified NoClobber. Either delete the file or specify a different name." 
            Return 
        } 

        # If attempting to write to a log file in a folder/path that doesn't exist create the file including the path. 
        elseif (!(Test-Path $Path)) { 
            Write-Verbose "Creating $Path." 
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File 
            } 

        else { 
            # Nothing to see here yet. 
        } 

        # Format Date for our Log File 
        $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"            

        # Write message to error, warning, or verbose pipeline and specify $LevelText 
        switch ($Level) { 
            'Error' { 
                Write-Error $Message 
                $LevelText = 'ERROR:' 
                } 
            'Warn' { 
                Write-Warning $Message 
                $LevelText = 'WARNING:' 
                } 
            'Info' { 
                Write-Verbose $Message 
                $LevelText = 'INFO:' 
                } 
            } 

        # Write log entry to $Path 
        "$FormattedDate $LevelText $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append 
    } 
    End 
    { 
    } 
}
```

and can call this function with `Write-Host`.
So whenever you will use `Write-Host`, its content will be saved the log file.
Example:
If you write

```
Write-Host "Execution starts!"
```

"Execution starts!" will be saved in the log file.

Comment: Does it have to be in the same file or can I just load it in the script?

Comment: Ok! Works but how should I detect Errors? And how can I say its a Error or Warning or Info? And if I put it in the Foreach Loop there are alot of the same lines in the log file. How can I say write this only once and go further?

Comment: You can keep this function in one separate file. What you need to do, just run that file once so that it will create `write-Host` cmdlet for saving log for that  particular session.

Comment: If you are catching the exception then you can write the occurred exception 
 in the log file with `write-host`.

Comment: If we talk about `Foreach`, then for sure it will record the log for each iteration. Further you can add more `if` conditions like where you do want to record or not.

Comment: It's a very bad practice to overload default cmdlets.